# Statement of total precipitation for each hour, day or month

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp, max

I store the data from the rain gauge in mySQL and needed help with listing the data. I save the data every 5 minutes and use the save date in the form of a timestamp.
At the end of each hour, therefore, HH: 55 will always be the maximum hourly total that I need to list for the day DD-MM-YYYY

Is it possible to list in the second SELECT a daily or monthly total of the data stored in this way? If so, how? Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Mysql version: 5.7.32-35-log I save the data every 5 minutes, but at the end of HH: 55 there is always the highest value for the hourly total precipitation.

So I have:

```
id | rain | timestamp
1 | 0.0 | 2021-10-04 12:00:00
2 | 0.0 | 2021-10-04 12:05:00
3 | 0.6 | 2021-10-04 12:10:00
4 | 0.9 | 2021-10-04 12:15:00
5 | 0.9 | 2021-10-04 12:20:00
6 | 1.4 | 2021-10-04 12:25:00
........
12 | 2.5 | 2021-10-04 12:55:00 // MAX rain

13 | 0.0 | 2021-10-04 13:00:00 // new hour and clean rain to 0.0
14 | 0.0 | 2021-10-04 13:05:00
15 | 0.6 | 2021-10-04 13:10:00
```

Comment: HI and welcome to the community. Please have a look at: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se. Do you mean that you will only ever record the value at xxh:55min? I.e. for 11:00 hours, you will only keep the reading for 11:55? You're question isn't clear. Please go to dbfiddle.uk and provide a fiddle with your table structure(s) and some sample data and your desired result!

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you instead of pick one point in time every hour, choose the maximum amount of rain per hour

```
SELECT date(ts), hour(ts), max(rain)
FROM t
GROUP BY date(ts), hour(ts)
```

Comment: MAX(rain) will always be for 55 mins past the hour. However, this is incorrect (should be at hour:59:59.999999999 and **very** counterintuitive) - see my answer - any comments welcome!

Comment: Given the sample data by the poster I get the impression that the sensor is read every 5 minutes and reset every hour?

Comment: Any how, max(rain) per hour should give the maximum amount, regardless of how often the sensor is read

Comment: `Given the sample data by the poster I get the impression that the sensor is read every 5 minutes and reset every hour?` - which is wrong - it misses the data from the final 5 minutes of the hour!

Comment: `MAX(rain)` should be on the hour (for the previous hour) and not 5 minutes to the hour - but you are correct - given the OP's current scenario, your answer will work - it will give the the value at `HOUR:55` - which I think is not the way it **should** be done! :-)

Comment: (a nit-pick) `DATETIME` is limited to 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is flawed. If you're measuring precipitation, then you want to measure from (a nano-second after) the beginning of the hour to the end of that hour (i.e. from 13:00:00.000000001 to 14:00:00.000000000) and not from a ns after 13:55 to 14:05.

Your approach essentially misses out on the 5 minutes of precipitation between 55 minutes past the hour and the hour mark!

This can be best shown by an example (the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=87dcdc221daa3eac9ae992c2e9291e49)):

```
CREATE TABLE prec -- precipitation and NOT rain! My dad was a meterologist
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  rain FLOAT NOT NULL,
  ts   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

populate it:

Now, I think that you're approaching this in the wrong way!

What you want is something more like the precipitation between, say, 13:00:00 and 13:05:00, and then between 13:05:00 and 13:10:00.

So, we assume that precipitation (**just after**) 13:00:00 is zero, but that a measurement **at** 13:00:00 represents it between 12:00:00 and 13:00:00, so I would have something more like this:

Basically, the first measurement for any period is at 5 minutes **past** the hour and **not** on the hour!

```
INSERT INTO prec VALUES

(0, 3.5, '2021-10-04 11:55:00'),
(1, 4.2, '2021-10-04 12:00:00'),  -- last measurement - highest

--
-- starts again after the hour
--


(2 ,  0.2, '2021-10-04 12:05:00'),  -- first measurement for period
(3 ,  0.6, '2021-10-04 12:10:00'),
(4 ,  0.9, '2021-10-04 12:15:00'),
(5 ,  0.9, '2021-10-04 12:20:00'),
(6 ,  1.4, '2021-10-04 12:25:00'),
(12,  2.5, '2021-10-04 12:55:00'),

(13, 2.6, '2021-10-04 13:00:00'),    -- last measurement for period


--
-- starts again **FROM** the hour!
--

(14,  0.1, '2021-10-04 13:05:00'),  -- 05:00 - lowest
(15,  0.6, '2021-10-04 13:10:00'),
(24,  1.5, '2021-10-04 13:55:00'),
(25,  1.8, '2021-10-04 14:00:00');  -- 00:00 - highest
```

### Queries:

### Query 1 (flawed)

```
SELECT 
  rain, ts, DATE(ts), HOUR(ts), MINUTE(ts)
FROM
  prec
WHERE MINUTE(ts) = 55;
```

Result:

```
rain    ts  DATE(ts)    HOUR(ts)    MINUTE(ts)
3.5     2021-10-04 11:55:00     2021-10-04  11  55
2.5     2021-10-04 12:55:00     2021-10-04  12  55
1.5     2021-10-04 13:55:00     2021-10-04  13  55
```

### Query 2 (correct way)

```
SELECT
  rain, ts, DATE(ts), HOUR(ts), MINUTE(ts)
FROM
  prec 
WHERE MINUTE(ts) = 0;
```

Result:

```
rain    ts  DATE(ts)    HOUR(ts)    MINUTE(ts)
4.2     2021-10-04 12:00:00     2021-10-04  12  0
2.6     2021-10-04 13:00:00     2021-10-04  13  0
1.8     2021-10-04 14:00:00     2021-10-04  14  0
```

So, the `MINUTE(ts) = 55` is missing out data!

You might be better off taking a cumulative approach to precipation over, say, a year and doing subtractions. With window functions (LAG()/LEAD()), this should be easy enough!

Comment: .Well, it is not "missing out data" if `:55` holds the 5-minute rainfall _starting_ at `:55`.

Comment: Agree on recording annual rainfall instead of rain-since-local-midnight. Avoids the problem with accumulation lost between the last observation and midnight.  You only have to deal with rollover once, at the beginning of your rain year. I recently converted my own site to use accumulated rainfall and the queries run __much__ faster and things like 'rain last 24 hours' are trivial to calculate. This of course assumes your weather station datalogger records accumulated rainfall.

Comment: @dwhitemv - this can actually have legal ramifications! One time, my dad told me about a guy who was obviously blind drunk and fell out of his own hotel room window... (yeah, I know...) and was trying to bring a case against the hotel - the court required an expert witness from Met Éireann to tell the court about weather conditions at the day and time in question!

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix hourly, daily, weekly, etc in a single table.  I *might* have 3 tables:

- A staging table for the 12 rows for the current hour (*starting* at :00, ..., :55).  It is `TRUNCATEd` each hour as the data is summarized into the next table.  (If you want the 5-minute details for longer, then don't promptly it.)
- A table with hourly data.  If this table will be eventually purged, I would `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))`
- A daily summary table, with totals for each day.
- No weekly (etc) summary table; such is easily enough derived from the daily table.

If this is only for rainfall, consider not storing hours or days with a value of "0".  This can make some queries more complex, but it will save a huge amount of space if you are in the Sahara.